# Overwrite jQuery method $.POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to overwrite the jQuery `$.post` method, parameters `url`.

I need to append a string to every script I have without editing them one by one. The string value may change because it's created by the system.

I know there's a way to overwrite at 100% the value of the parameter but not just appending.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a custom function:

```
var updateUrl = function(url){

  return url + someStuff

}

$.post(

  updateUrl( yourUrl ),
  data,
  successCallback

);
```

So you wrap the overriding logic once in `updateUrl`, and that's it.

Comment: he specifically said he didn't want to modify every script

Comment: The update is a trivial single operation with any decent IDE btw, but nevertheless you are right.

Comment: You know what, I may use your idea... it's simple and once it's done, it's done and working !

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the modifications you want to do, you may use one off [.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) or [.ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) methods to override the url parameter.

In a general way, you can modify an existing JavaScript function using the "Duck Punching pattern". You can read this article by Paul Irish to know how it works http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/

Here's is the final pattern he recommends for using with jQuery

```
(function($){

    // store original reference to the method
    var _old = $.fn.method;

    $.fn.method = function(arg1,arg2){

        if ( ... condition ... ) {
           return  .... 
        } else {           // do the default
           return _old.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```